# Spring boot application - how to print logs in Json format

Tags: spring-boot, logging, slf4j, spring-logback

I need to print logs in pretty Json format, with all details.

Currently I have my small service on spring boot and application.yml configuration file. I have below configuration for logging;

```
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org:
      springframework:
        security: INFO
        web: INFO
      hibernate: INFO
      apache:
        commons:
          dbcp2: INFO
  file: ../logs/myLog.log
  pattern:
    console: '%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:s  s.SSS} %-5level [%thread] %logger{15} - %msg%n'
```

Could you please advise me is there any configuration to change appender, so I could get logs in Json format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a file named *logback-spring.xml* in folder *src/main/resources* with a content similar to this one:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
    </appender>
    <logger name="jsonLogger" additivity="false" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Second add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
  <version>6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And that's it.

You should see lines similar to this one:

```
{"@timestamp":"2018-10-11T23:48:57.215+00:00","@version":1,"message":"Sample TRACE Message","logger_name":"com.example.demo.LoggingExample","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-1","level":"TRACE","level_value":5000}
```

See [full example](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/java?topic=java-spring-logging) for more details.